# Nexus 5 with zero-length partitions

Tags: nexus-5, hardware, file-system

So something is wrong with either the partition or the eMMC. TWRP is unable to erase/reformat/repair any partition (console lists partitions that fail to mount: /data, /data/media, /system, /cache) and e2fsck -pcfv /dev/block/mmcblk0p27 says it is zero-length partition. In fact, under TWRP, the partition sizes are System(0MB), Data(0MB), Cache(12MB), Boot(22MB), EFS(6MB). Any help?

Comment: Have you double-checked if the info shown by TWRP is correct by checking with [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best shot at this point is to [flash a factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en#hammerhead). Complete instructions are at the top of that page, but the general gist is:

- Download and extract the factory image (you'll probably want the latest one - MRA58K)
- Boot your device into fastboot mode (in TWRP go to reboot -> bootloader, or run `adb reboot bootloader`)
- Run the `flash-all` script (make sure that `fastboot` from the SDK is in your PATH - `set PATH=<path-to-fastboot-folder>;%PATH%` in windows, and `export PATH=<path-to-fastboot-folder>:$PATH` in OSX/Linux)
- Your device should work again! You'll have to flash TWRP again, though.